# Control proximity sensor on Galaxy SII

Tags: sensors, proximity, infrared, remote-control

The proximity sensor on Samsung Galaxy S II phone consists of infrared LED and IR sensor.
Is it possible to control infrared LED of proximity sensor in an arbitrary way (to do a TV remote control or to transfer something via IRDA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The light/proximity-sensor hardware-IC does NOT provide any control to modulate the IR signal. It simply projects an IR signal at a constant frequency.